# How to execute the gcloud api to move the alias IP from one instance to another instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have 2 instances in GCP, one instance is configured with static private ip and alias IP. Another instance has only static IP no alias IP. 
Is it possible to move the alias IP from one instance to another. Want to know if gcloud api exists to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using gcloud commands

```
gcloud compute instances network-interfaces update instance-1 --zone=xxx --aliases=""
gcloud compute instances network-interfaces update instance-2 --zone=xxx --aliases="ip_address"
```